# HTTPS on Ubuntu instance Amazon EC2

Tags: apache2, dns, amazon-ec2, https

I have a question which I hope somebody can answer for me.

My situation: I have an Ubuntu Server running Apache2 on a EC2 Amazon instance, which is serving an OwnCloud instance.

My goal: I want to deploy HTTPS on this instance. I already configured the security group to allow HTTPS traffic from anywhere (as the server should be accessible from anywhere on the internet). We already have a domain name bar.com registered at another domain hosting company. But we want to point foo.bar.com to this owncloud installation.

My questions:

1. Which IP-address do I use to configure the DNS at this domain hosting company. Because the public ip-address and public DNS of the EC2 instance is renewed every time the instance restarts.
2. How do I generate the SSL certificate for HTTPS configuration of Apache2? More specifically, which common name (CN) do I need to put in the certificate. Because the public dns of the EC2 instance is changing on every restart. I think if I put the foo.bar.com CN in the certificate that the browser will throw a certificate error once the user gets redirected from foo.bar.com -> .compute.amazonaws.com, am I right?

In short: how do I deploy https on a EC2 instance at Amazon AWS with a dns at a third party domain name service?

Answer (score 0):

1 st Question Answer:

Your IP is changing continuously because you dont have take Elastic IP
So please create Elastic IP and Select  particular Instance for that. Then your issue of changing IP every restart will slove.

2nd Question Answer:

You need to install SSL certificate for that to HTTPS

You can be install SSL on AWS by selecting Classic Load Balancer.